# Phonegap alarm clock application

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an alarm clock application with jquery mobile and phonegap. When user click **SET ALARM button** I am adding alarm time to HTML5 localStorage and I am calling a recursive function with setTimout. In recursive function ı am comparing now and user set alarm time. It is woring great. But this scenario is valid on application runs everytime. **How can ı do my application works background?**  User shouldn't close my application anytime when user set alarm.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using localNotification plugin.